# ¿Cómo soluciono el error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS en Laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Tengo un controlador que gestiona la autenticación, pero al momento de crear el middleware, tengo el error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, si al middleware lo dejo únicamente con `return $next($request);` sigue el flujo normal del programa, pero el middleware no obviamente no hace las validaciones.

Cabe mencionar que el envío de los inputs del formulario los hago por ajax al controlador directamente, no sé si algo tenga que ver pero de todas formas adjunto esa parte del código.

**Solicitud Ajax**

```
<script !src="">
$(document).on('click', '#login', function (e) {
    /* EVITAR EVENTO DEFAULT DEL BOTON */
    e.preventDefault();

    let email = $('#email').val();
    // alert(email);
    let password = $('#password').val();
    // alert(password);

    $.ajax({
        url    : '{{url('admin/auth')}}',
        method : 'post',
        data   : {
            _token  : '{{csrf_token()}}',
            email   : email,
            password: password
        },
        success: (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if (data !== 'Éxito') {
                toastr.options = {
                    'closeButton'      : false,
                    'debug'            : false,
                    'newestOnTop'      : false,
                    'progressBar'      : false,
                    'positionClass'    : 'toast-top-right',
                    'preventDuplicates': false,
                    'onclick'          : null,
                    'showDuration'     : '300',
                    'hideDuration'     : '1000',
                    'timeOut'          : '5000',
                    'extendedTimeOut'  : '1000',
                    'showEasing'       : 'swing',
                    'hideEasing'       : 'linear',
                    'showMethod'       : 'fadeIn',
                    'hideMethod'       : 'fadeOut'
                };
                toastr.error(data);
            } else if (data === 'Éxito') {
                toastr.options = {
                    'closeButton'      : false,
                    'debug'            : false,
                    'newestOnTop'      : false,
                    'progressBar'      : false,
                    'positionClass'    : 'toast-top-right',
                    'preventDuplicates': false,
                    'onclick'          : null,
                    'showDuration'     : '300',
                    'hideDuration'     : '1000',
                    'timeOut'          : '5000',
                    'extendedTimeOut'  : '1000',
                    'showEasing'       : 'swing',
                    'hideEasing'       : 'linear',
                    'showMethod'       : 'fadeIn',
                    'hideMethod'       : 'fadeOut'
                };
                toastr.success(data);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    window.location = '{{route('admin.dashboard')}}';
                }, 1500);
                {{--window.location = '{{url('admin/dashboard')}}';--}}
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

**Controlador de Autenticación**

```
    public function index(Request $request) {
            return view('backend.auth', [
                'title' => 'Login',
                'description' => 'Login del backend del sistema del Ingeniero David Paucar'
            ]);
        }

public function authentication(Request $request) {

$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'email' => ['required', 'email'],
                'password' => ['required', 'min:6']
            ], $messages = [
                'email.required' => 'El :attribute es obligatorio',
                'password.required' => 'La :attribute es obligatoria',
                'email' => 'El :attribute debe ser un :attribute válido',
                'min' => 'La :attribute debe tener al menos 6 caracteres'
            ], [
                'password' => 'contraseña'
            ]);

            $error = $validator->errors();

            $userInfo = Admin::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();

            if ($error) {

                foreach ($error->all() as $message) {

                    return $message;
                }

                if (!$userInfo) {
                    return 'Las credenciales ingresadas no coinciden con los registrados';
                } else {
                    if (Hash::check($request->password, $userInfo->password)) {
                        $request->session()->put('LoggedUser', $userInfo->email);
                        return 'Éxito';
                    }
                }

            }
}

public function dashboard() {
            $data = [
                'LoggedUser' => Admin::where('email', '=', session('LoggedUser'))->first(),
                'title' => 'Dashboard'
            ];
            return view('backend.dashboard', $data);
        }

public function exit(Request $request) {
            Auth::logout();
            $request->session()->flush();
            return route('admin');
        }
```

**Middleware**

Si lo tengo de la siguiente manera sucede el error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
        if (!session()->has('LoggedUser')) {
            return redirect('admin');
        }

        if (session()->has('LoggedUser')) {
            return back();
        }
        return $next($request);

    }
```

Pero si lo dejo de la siguiente manera ahí sigue el flujo del programa pero obviamente porque no tiene ninguna validación.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
       
        return $next($request);

    }
```

**Rutas**

Por último adjunto mis rutas que creo son sencillas pero el problema que me genera no logro encontrar el por qué.

```
    Route::post('admin/auth', [AuthController::class, 'authentication'])->name('admin.auth');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('admin', [AuthController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('admin/dashboard', [AuthController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
});

Route::get('admin/exit', [AuthController::class, 'exit'])->name('admin.exit');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar agregándole `withoutMiddleware` a mi ruta que gestiona las solicitudes ajax que gestiona la autenticación al controlador, supongo que tuve el error ya la ruta está agrupada y se ejecuta el middleware globalmente.

```
Route::post('admin/auth', [AuthController::class, 'authentication'])->name('admin.auth')->withoutMiddleware('admin');
```